# Cryptocurrency bitcoin back testing returns

Tags: python, r, bitcoin, quantitative-finance, quantstrat

I want to know the USD returns while back testing crypto pairs. 
For example backtesting BTC_ETH will show returns in BTC, but i want the relative USD returns. (as USD_BTC will be changing over the time series) 
I'm thinking i need both time series BTC_ETH and USD_BTC and either work out the value of USD_BTC at the open and close of each trade, or multiply the returns of both pairs while the trade is open.

I use Quantstrat (plus the usual dependencies)
I also use python for execution, but i rather R for modelling.

Is there a similar solution in forex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea and a great way to lose a lot of money.

Say you trade BTC and ETH. You can book a USD profit on every single trade and still have a massive loss. Why? Because you may wind up holding lots of BTC when the BTC price is going down and lots of ETH when the ETH price is going down.

Imagine if you start with $1,000 in BTC and ETH, have a day of trading and wind up booking $100 in profit. But then overnight, the price of ETH halves and BTC doubles but you are holding all ETH. So your $1,100 turns to $550.

The next day you trade and book $100 in profit, so you're up to $650. But then overnight, the price of ETH goes back up but BTC halves and you are holding all BTC. So now you have $325 worth of ETH.

What happened? You booked $200 in trading profits, no trading losses, but your $1,000 in BTC turned into $325 worth of ETH.

And, yes, this really happens. When BTC is going up, people will want to buy your BTC. So you'll be holding less when it's going up. When BTC is going down, people will want to sell their BTC to you. So you'll wind up holding more when it's going down.

Ack!

Comment: When you say "btc and eth" I assuming you mean long btc_eth? If I make a long btc_eth trade and it goes down, I can still make a USD profit, because relatively they may both be rising compared to the USD, and vice versa I could make a loss of btc_eth goes up I could still make a loss as relatively they may be going down compared to USD.

Comment: @GeV126 No, that's not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about losses taken because your holding currency's price movement is negatively correlated with the quantity of it that you're holding. Read my example more carefully.

Comment: Your end game is probably to end up with bitcoin, mine is to end up with USD, i want to know the relative USD profit/loss of all trades. Its like my local currency is USD, and i'm in a AUD/JPY trade, if both those currencies are falling like a stone in comparison to USD it doesn't matter what profit i make, i'm still loosing because eventually i'm going to need to convert back to USD. Have you ever traded forex?

Comment: @GeV126 I've been trading forex and cryptos for about a decade now. You don't seem to understand the difference between trading forex (with leverage and no need to hold the assets after you close a long) and trading cryptos (with no leverage and ownership of assets when trades close). Please read my answer again very carefully.

Comment: David i'm educating myself as fast as i can on the matter, i appreciate your responses. I know there are some differences as you have mentioned, trying to get my head around them. thanks again.

Comment: I think what i am alluding to only holding crypto during the trade and going back to USD until the next trade, It seems this isn't feasible with crypto trading. Not like forext where you borrow one currency to buy the next, when you close out the trade you only end up with profit/loss.